# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"undefined\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"students\""

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I have a problem in my CRUD application using Node JS, Express, and Mongo DB. Actually, I am just following this tutorial but I get stuck on the UPDATE part. I am able to CREATE, READ, and DELETE values from database already, but I don't know why I keep getting this error whenever I try to UPDATE my data.

I found the error is from my controller.js file and here's the code:

```
exports.update = (req,res)=>{
    if(!req.body){
        return res
        .status(400)
        .send({message:"Record to be updated can not be empty!"})
    }
     
    const id = req.params.id;
    studentDb.findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,{userFindAndModify:false})
    .then(data=>{
        if(!data){
            res.status(404).send({message:`Cannot update student record with ID ${id}. Maybe record not found.`})
        }else{
            res.send(data)
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).send({message:`Error in updating student record with id=${id}.` + err})
    })
}
```

My hypothesis is that the objectID goes on the first model in my schema because whenever I check the console when I run the application, the last value of the model in my schema, the "contact" goes undefined.

The ERROR:

[image]

[image]

I can provide the other codes related to this if my question is still unclear. Thank you in advance for answering! I've been stuck here for hours already.

**EDIT**

Here's the additional front-end code
(this is the FORM part from my update_student.ejs where I update the data):

```
<!-- form handling -->
            <form method="POST" id="update_student">
                <div class="new_student">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label for="firstName" class="text-muted">First Name</label><br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=students._id%>">
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<%=students.firstName%>" placeholder="Corki">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label for="middleName" class="text-muted">Middle Name</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="middleName" value="<%=students.middleName%>" placeholder="Vi">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label for="lastName" class="text-muted">Last Name</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<%=students.lastName%>" placeholder="Fortune">
                        </div> 
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="gender" class="text-muted">Gender</label><br>
                                <div class="radio inline">
                                    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="gender" value="Male" <% if(students.gender == "Male"){ %>checked <% } %>>
                                    <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Male</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio inline">
                                    <input type="radio"id="radio-3" name="gender" value="Female" <% if(students.gender == "Female"){ %>checked <% } %>>
                                    <label for="radio-3" class="radio-label">Female</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="birthday" class="text-muted">Birthday</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="birthday" value="<%=students.birthday%>" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="program" class="text-muted">Program</label>
                                <input type="text" name="program" value="<%=students.program%>" placeholder="i.e. BSIT">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="yearLevel" class="text-muted">Year Level</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="yearLevel">
                                    <option value="">Select year level</option>
                                    <option <% if(students.yearLevel == "First Year"){ %>selected <% } %> value="First Year">First Year</option>
                                    <option <% if(students.yearLevel == "Second Year"){ %>selected <% } %> value="Second Year">Second Year</option>
                                    <option <% if(students.yearLevel == "Third Year"){ %>selected <% } %> value="Third Year">Third Year</option>
                                    <option <% if(students.yearLevel == "Fourth Year"){ %>selected <% } %> value="Fourth Year">Fourth Year</option>
                                    <option <% if(students.yearLevel == "Fifth Year"){ %>selected <% } %> value="Fifth Year">Fifth Year</option>
                                    <option <% if(students.yearLevel == "Masteral"){ %>selected <% } %> value="Masteral">Masteral</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="text-muted">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<%=students.email%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="text-muted">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" value="<%=students.address%>" placeholder="Household No., Barangay, City, Province">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contact" class="text-muted">Contact</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact" value="<%=students.contact%>" placeholder="i.e 09XX-XXX-XXXX">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn text-dark update">Save</button>
                    </div>
            
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- form handling -->
```

Code for my #update_student JS just in case:

```
$('#update_student').on("submit",(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
    var data = {}
    $.map(unindexed_array,function(n,i){
        data[n['firstName']] = n['value']
    })
    console.log(data);

    var request={
        "url": `http://localhost:1485/api/students/${data.id}`,
        "method":"PUT",
        "data" : data
    }
    $.ajax(request).done(function(response){
        alert("Data updated successfully!");
    })
}))
```

Comment: Clearly `id` value is not passing, it's `undefined`. Looks like front end issue

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath hello, Sir. I checked the front end and I called the "_id" there from the MongoDB. Even when I check it on the console when I'm running it, the "_id" is read but when I submit the changes it become undefined.

Comment: Ok, but the _id from frontend is not getting passed. If you provide frontend code, we can check.

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath okay, Sir, I edited my question and added my front-end code (also JS) there.

Comment: ok, so what this `console.log(data);` is printing in console?

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath I expect it to print the array of the updated data but instead I keep on receiving "{undefined: "09781234576"}" , which is supposed to be the "contact" data from my MongoDB database.

Comment: what is `unindexed_array` prints? Can you check? I guess `data[n['firstName']] = n['value']` always checking the first name property which is causing the issue.

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath the unindexed_array prints the complete array, including the ID. I tried to change "data[n['firstName']] = n['value']" to "data[n['id']] = n['value']" but there's still the "PUT http://localhost:1485/api/students/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)."

Comment: Can you share the `unindexed_array` output?

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath here, Sir:

0: {name: "id", value: "60fa8eb8869a3f39349cf2b8"}
1: {name: "firstName", value: "Lamba"}
2: {name: "middleName", value: "Dada"}
3: {name: "lastName", value: "Do"}
4: {name: "gender", value: "Male"}
5: {name: "birthday", value: "12/13/2000"}
6: {name: "program", value: "BSIT"}
7: {name: "yearLevel", value: "Third Year"}
8: {name: "email", value: "example9@gmail.com"}
9: {name: "address", value: "Seoul, South Korea"}
10: {name: "contact", value: "09781234576"}
length: 11
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath, thank you Sir, I already figure it out. Thank you for asking me to share my "unindexed_array" output. I looked into it and realize that I should write "data[n['name']] = n['value']" instead of "data[n['firstName']] = n['value']".

Comment: Amazing  .....   .. ..

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath Thank you so much, Sir for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sir @Rajdeep Debnath 's help, I was able to look into may "unindexed_array" from my console.log and figured out that instead of `data[n['firstName']] = n['value']`
I should write `data[n['name']] = n['value']`

I wrote the former because I thought it is just the name of the variable but in actuality, it is like the "id" or "class" called in JavaScript. The form used "name" on the inputs (like `<input type="text" name="program" value="<%=students.program%>" placeholder="i.e. BSIT">` from my code) so that's why it is the one called in the function instead.

Now my code for my #update_student JS goes like this:

```
$('#update_student').on("submit",(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
    var data = {}
    $.map(unindexed_array,function(n,i){
        data[n['name']] = n['value']
    })
    console.log(data);

    var request={
        "url": `http://localhost:1485/api/students/${data.id}`,
        "method":"PUT",
        "data" : data
    }
    $.ajax(request).done(function(response){
        alert("Data updated successfully!");
    })
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply change your Url path with ``` `` ```symbol instead of ''.

Just like that

```
var request={
        "url": `http://localhost:1485/api/students/${data.id}`,
        "method":"PUT",
        "data" : data
    }
```